# Machinist, how do I reference the object I'm making and pass it to an association? (AssociationTypeMismatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, machinist

I'm trying to build factories for relatively complex models.

I have a Pressroom model, which belongs to Source, and Source has many Pressrooms. When creating the Source, if pressrooms is empty, an initial pressroom is created in an after_create filter.
The pressroom site must be unique per source.

```
class Source
  has_many :pressrooms
  after_create :create_initial_pressroom! # if pressrooms.empty?
  ...
end

class Pressroom
  belongs_to :source
  # source.pressrooms.map(&:site) should have unique elements
  validate_on_create :check_unique_site
end
```

This leads to my problem: My `Pressroom.make` fails, because it builds a Source, which has no pressrooms, so the `after_create` callback creates one, and when the `Pressroom.make` tries to finish up, its site is not unique. I don't want to create two pressrooms when I run `Pressroom.make`

My attempt to solve this is to make the source association in the pressroom blueprint reference the pressroom. Sort of what `Source.create :pressrooms => [Pressroom.new]` would do.

```
Pressroom.blueprint do
  source { Source.make :pressrooms => [self] }
  site { source.site }
end
```

Unfortunatly, `self` is not yet a Pressroom. It's an instance of Machinist::Lathe, so I get an ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch exception.

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to factories and Machinist. I don't want to have to change the business logic, and I want to be able to cleanly make pressrooms with `Pressroom.make` without making two pressrooms in the process. If switching to factory-girl would help, I'm open to that.

I'd be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Googling around, I found some hints on http://webcrisps.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/stubbing-before_create-callbacks-in-a-machinist-blueprint/ – to stub the `after_create :create_initial_pressroom!` callback on Source, in the Source blueprint – using Machinist 2 and Mocha here:

```
Pressroom.blueprint do
  source { Source.make!(:without_initial_pressroom) }
  site   { object.source.site }
end

Source.blueprint do
  site
end

Source.blueprint(:without_initial_pressroom) do
  object.stubs(:create_initial_pressroom!).returns(true)
end
```

This way, `Pressroom.make!` works like it should, `Source.make!` works like it should, and... I guess I'm happy. But still a bit perplexed by the problems I ran into in the solution I tried above (both in machinist 1 and 2).

If anyone knows how to make this work with `object`, let me know. It'd be a lot cleaner, and besides, I generally don't like accepting my own answers here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Machinist 1 or 2? These suggestions for Machinist 2 and may or may not work in Machinist 1. I can't remember how you do this in Machinist 1 (and can't be bothered to google!).

To do it in the way you're suggesting, you need to use `object`:

```
Pressroom.blueprint do
  source { Source.make :pressrooms => [object] }
  site { source.site }
end
```

But a much nicer way to do it is to take advantage of the fact Machinst knows about the models associations and just let it do its thing:

```
Pressroom.blueprint do
  source
  site { source.site }
end
```

Assuming your associations are setup correctly, that *should* work. See the [Blueprints wiki page](https://github.com/notahat/machinist/wiki/Blueprints) for more.

Comment: I'm using machinist 1, but I'll try out version 2. `object` didn't work in version 1, it set my source to `nil`. The problem with the simple blueprint is that a `Pressroom.make` will do a `Source.make`, which runs the after_create callback, creates a pressroom, returns to Pressroom.make, which fails due to the unique constraint.

Comment: I've now tried with machinist 2 also, but it doesn't seem to work. `Pressroom.make!` throws `undefined method `site' for nil:NilClass`. Source isn't set. I've tried different approaches in the blueprint: `source`, `source { Source.make! :pressrooms => [object] }`, `site { source.site }`, `site { object.source.site }` ... all I get is `undefined method 'site'` :/

Comment: hmmm, I think `object.source.site` is correct in machinist 2, but when it's being called, perhaps source been made yet. Did you try the combination of `make!` on the source, with `object.source.size` for the site?

Comment: yup, tried that… now looking into an alternative solution based on http://webcrisps.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/stubbing-before_create-callbacks-in-a-machinist-blueprint/ – stubbing the after_create callback. Not quite what I wanted, since I'd prefer a Source.make! to behave normally.